# How print automatically print addresses on envelop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print hundreds of addresses on envelops using javascript. I was able implement this using the code below

```js
  function combineSenderInfo(){
    var from = "<div style='padding-top:0px'><h5> </h5>"
    var name = "" + "<br>";
  
    var address = "1107 Test Av" + "<br>" + "Test, Pa 19111" + "<br>";
    var phone = " " + "</div>";
  
    return from + name + address + phone;
  }
  
  function combineReceiverInfo(recieverData){
    var from =   "<br>" +"<div style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto;  '><h3> "
    var name = recieverData["name"] + "</h3>";
    var address = "<h3 style=''>" + recieverData["address1"]  + "<br>" + recieverData["address2"]+ "<br>" ;
    var phone = recieverData["phone"] + "</h3></div>";
    return from + name + address + phone;
  }
```

```js
  function AddressesPrintManager(MassAddressDict){


    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
   
    printWindow.document.write('</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('<style>* { font-family: sans-serif } p { margin:0px 0; }h6{display:inline; text-transform:uppercase}</style><style media="print">@page { size: size: 4.5in 9.5in landscape;margin: 0; } </style>');  
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;height: 90%;box-sizing: border-box;padding-top:0px">');
   
  
    var padding = 200
    Object.keys(MassAddressDict).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key + " " + MassAddressDict[key]);

        var recieverData = MassAddressDict[key]

        var senderInfo = combineSenderInfo();
        //var packageDetails = combinePackageDetails();
        var receiverInfo = combineReceiverInfo(recieverData);

        var index = Object.keys(MassAddressDict).indexOf(key);
        
        //padding = padding - 1.5
        console.log("Padding increased to ", padding)
        printWindow.document.write(`<div id="label${index}" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">`);
        printWindow.document.write(senderInfo);
        //printWindow.document.write(packageDetails);
        printWindow.document.write(`<p style='padding-bottom: 95px'></p>`)

        printWindow.document.write('</div>');
        printWindow.document.write(receiverInfo);
        printWindow.document.write(`<p style='padding-bottom: ${padding}px'></p>`)
    });
    printWindow.document.write('</body></3html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
    


  }
```

the code above produces this

[image]

but as it gets to around the 20th page, the address placement becomes significantly off like this

[image]

I have tried adjusting the padding with

```
    padding = padding - 1.5
```

but this method does not work. Does anyone know how I can fix the drifting address placement after some pages?

Comment: You need to control your page breaks. Probably using `page-break-before: always;`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey how could i implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a page break for each envelope. Each envelope is a different page, and predicting exactly how tall each envelop is will probably never work. Put a div around the entire thing:

```
    printWindow.document.write('<div style="page-break-after:always;">');
    printWindow.document.write('<div id="label${index}" 
    style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;">');
    printWindow.document.write(senderInfo);
    printWindow.document.write(`<p style='padding-bottom: 95px'></p>`)

    printWindow.document.write('</div>');
    printWindow.document.write(receiverInfo);
    printWindow.document.write('</div>');
```

Be sure to remove your `<p>` with the padding, to avoid creating blank pages.